# Getting the value of href attributes in all <a> tags on a html file with Python

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing

I'm building an app in python, and I need to get the URL of all links in one webpage. I already have a function that uses urllib to download the html file from the web, and transform it to a list of strings with readlines().

Currently I have this code that uses regex (I'm not very good at it) to search for links in every line:

```
for line in lines:
    result = re.match ('/href="(.*)"/iU', line)
    print result
```

This is not working, as it only prints "None" for every line in the file, but I'm sure that at least there are 3 links on the file I'm opening.

Can someone give me a hint on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Sigh*, another one of those questions trying to parse HTML/XML with regular expressions. FYI, this is not recommended, use a parser, as suggested by eduffy.

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expressions? Why is htmllib not an option?

Comment: Well, mostly because I was trying to learn some regex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just for completeness I will add here what I found to be the best answer, and I found it on the book Dive Into Python, from Mark Pilgrim.

Here follows the code to list all URL's from a webpage:

```
from sgmllib import SGMLParser

class URLLister(SGMLParser):
    def reset(self):                              
        SGMLParser.reset(self)
        self.urls = []

    def start_a(self, attrs):                     
        href = [v for k, v in attrs if k=='href']  
        if href:
            self.urls.extend(href)

import urllib, urllister
usock = urllib.urlopen("http://diveintopython.net/")
parser = urllister.URLLister()
parser.feed(usock.read())         
usock.close()      
parser.close()                    
for url in parser.urls: print url
```

Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 11):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) can do this almost trivially:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = soup('<body><a href="123">qwe</a><a href="456">asd</a></body>')
print [tag.attrMap['href'] for tag in html.findAll('a', {'href': True})]
```

Comment: That does it perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative to BeautifulSoup is lxml (http://lxml.de/);

```
import lxml.html
links = lxml.html.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/").xpath("//a/@href")
for link in links:
    print link
```

Answer (score 4):

There's an HTML parser that comes standard in Python.  Checkout `htmllib`.

Comment: htmllib is deprecated in python 3.0, so for the sake of future compatibility, I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

What others haven't told you is that using regular expressions for this is not a reliable solution.
Using regular expression will give you wrong results on many situations: if there are <A> tags that are commented out, or if there are text in the page which include the string "href=", or if there are <textarea> elements with html code in it, and many others. Plus, the href attribute may exist on tags other that the anchor tag.

What you need for this is [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath), which is a query language for DOM trees, i.e. it lets you retrieve any set of nodes satisfying the conditions you specify (HTML attributes are nodes in the DOM).
XPath is a well standarized language now a days ([W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath)), and is well supported by all major languages. I strongly suggest you use XPath and not regexp for this.
adw's answer shows one example of using XPath for your particular case.

Answer (score 3):

As previously mentioned: regex does not have the power to parse HTML. Do not use regex for parsing HTML. Do not pass Go. Do not collect £200.

Use an HTML parser.

But for completeness, the primary problem is:

```
re.match ('/href="(.*)"/iU', line)
```

You don't use the “/.../flags” syntax for decorating regexes in Python. Instead put the flags in a separate argument:

```
re.match('href="(.*)"', line, re.I|re.U)
```

Another problem is the greedy ‘.*’ pattern. If you have two hrefs in a line, it'll happily suck up all the content between the opening " of the first match and the closing " of the second match. You can use the non-greedy ‘.*?’ or, more simply, ‘[^"]*’ to only match up to the first closing quote.

But don't use regexes for parsing HTML. Really.

Answer (score 1):

Don't divide the html content into lines, as there maybe multiple matches in a single line. Also don't assume there is always quotes around the url.

Do something like this:

```
links = re.finditer(' href="?([^\s^"]+)', content)

for link in links:
  print link
```