# Python: how to extract the content of a column in a table

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div>
    <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>stuff</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>The content I want</div> 
           </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

How do I get "the content I want" and delete all html tags?

Thanks

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671323/getting-the-value-of-href-attributes-in-all-a-tags-on-a-html-file-with-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), e.g.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> text = """<div>
...     <table>
...        <tbody>
...           <tr>
...             <td>stuff</td>
...           </tr>
...           <tr>
...             <td>
...               <div>The content I want</div> 
...            </td>
...            </tr>
...         </tbody>
...       </table>
... </div>"""
>>> a = bs(text)
```

Since all the `<tr>` tags have some content and you need the data from the *second* row, you cant just use `a.text`, but need to do something a bit more complex:

```
>>> a.table.tbody.findAll("tr")[1].div.text
u'The content I want'
```

Or, if there really is only one `<div>` tag on the table rows (`<tr>`), you can also just traverse the tags e.g:

```
>>> a.table.tbody.div.text
u'The content I want'
```

Or you can use the html parser from [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module as follows:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> t = html.fromstring(text)
>>> t.xpath("table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div")[0].text
'The content I want'
```

Comment: well, actually there are other contents in the tags

Comment: Well, then actually revise your question.

Answer (score 1):

I personally have done a lot of scraping and use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (a very popular add-on for Firefox) to inspect the html and layout of the website and then use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (Python library, extensively used to scrape information from websites). Both the tools fairly complement each other.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), it's a really great library for parsing HTML/XML. The docs are pretty good and there are examples on how to extract particular tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use a XML parser like `lxml`. You won't have to delete anything. You will just extract the data from that div.

As you only have a single `div`, a valid XPath query might be `//div`

As elegant and simple as BeautifulSoup might seem, it is not language-agnostic like XPath expressions.

Comment: Why would you need something language agnostic to find something from HTML?

Comment: Because BeautifulSoup skills won't be transferable to any other language other than Python. Also, BeautifulSoup is not actively developed and is known to be buggy for Py3k.

Comment: not actively developed? What are you talking about - last beta update for BS4 was 4 days ago?!

Comment: My bad. Looks like things have changed since I last had a look. At that time the main developer said that he was abandoning the project, and did not recommend relying on BS in the future (as many other answers here on SO reflect).

Comment: Fair enough, added `lxml` example to my answer

Comment: Fair enough, added +1 to your answer :D